# transform text from uppercase to capitalize

Tags: css

How can I transform a text from uppercase to capital case using CSS only?

For example change this text " THIS IS A TEXT. " to " This Is A Text. "

Comment: there is no way to do this in css , if your text in the html is in uppercase itself !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik There is a way, please take a look https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-transform

Comment: @DipteeH It doesn't work if the text is already uppercase https://jsfiddle.net/L6kxozng/

Comment: I want to do it with CSS if it's possible.

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting the question. It's a real struggle that CSS doesn't have a solution for this problem.

Comment: Probably because this question has been asked a lot before and all the duplicates say you either need to use your server side language or js to lowercase it first

Comment: Use JS for this. its not possible with only css

Answer (score -1):

With the help of  text-transform css property [**Check details  here**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-transform)

Comment: That doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @YassineYounes You can make use of js function transfer it to lower and then apply class

Answer (score -2):

Like this.    `text-transform: capitalize;`

**EDIT**: If the text is written in uppercase then it's impossible with just css.

Comment: That won't work if the text is in uppercase to begin with.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes just need to override, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/apgfrmey/1/

Comment: Not sure what your Fiddle is trying to show but no, it doesn't work when the text is already uppercase https://jsfiddle.net/L6kxozng/

Comment: @HiddenHobbes is right. It does not work on uppercase

Comment: Ho by uppercase he means a text written in uppercase and not stylize in uppercase? Well, impossible :/

Comment: "text-transform: capitalize" works only when the text is initially lower case.

Comment: @YassineYounes then it's impossible in css only. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

The text-transform property in CSS controls text case and capitalization.

```
.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }
```

"this is a text" 
"This Is A Text"

**capitalize** capitalizes the **first letter of each word** in the selected text.

It does not makes the remaining text lowercases , that is why "THIS IS A TEXT" will not change to "This Is A Text". For This:-
You have to first lowercase the texts and then capitalize it.

**capitalize** only affects the first letters of words. It will not change the case of the rest of the letters in a word. For example, if you **capitalize** a word that's in all capital letters already, the other letters in the word won't switch to lowercase. This is nice when your text includes an acronym or abbreviation that shouldn't include any lowercase letters.

Comment: "text-transform: capitalize" works only when the text is initially lower case.

Comment: This is because : - capitalize only affects the first letters of words. It will not change the case of the rest of the letters in a word. For example, if you capitalize a word that's in all capital letters already, the other letters in the word won't switch to lowercase. This is nice when your text includes an acronym or abbreviation that shouldn't include any lowercase letters.